# How to wrap method calls with await?

Tags: c#, methods, proxy, wrapper, async-await

All calls to the service should work through personal channel. So all methods which have access to the server proxy should look like this one:

```
public async Task<SDRLocation[]> FindLocationsAsync(string searchString)
    {
        ChannelFactory<IQueryService> channel = new ChannelFactory<IQueryService>("SomeServ_IQuery");
        channel.Open();
        SomeProxy = channel.CreateChannel();
        Location[] locationEntitiesFound = await SomeProxy.FindLocationsAsync(searchString);
        ((IChannel)SomeProxy ).Close();

        return locationEntitiesFound.Select(x => new SDRLocation(x)).ToArray();
    }
```

But because I have a lot of methods like this service calls I tried to avoid code duplication and create this method wrapper:

```
public TResult HandleServiceCall<TResult>(Func<IPlantOrgQueryService, TResult> serviceMethod)
    {
        ChannelFactory<IQueryService> channel = new ChannelFactory<IQueryService>("SomeServ_IQuery");
        channel.Open();
        IQueryService newProxy = channel.CreateChannel();
        TResult results = serviceMethod(newProxy);
        ((IChannel)newProxy).Close();

         return results;
    }
```

now I expect to make everywhere calls like this :

```
public async Task<SDRLocation[]> FindLocationsAsync(string searchString)
    {
        Location[] locationEntitiesFound = await HandleServiceCall(x => x.FindLocationsAsync(searchString));

        return locationEntitiesFound.Select(x => new SDRLocation(x)).ToArray();
    }
```

But I end up with error "The communication object, System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientReliableDuplexSessionChannel, cannot be used for communication because it has been Aborted."

Not understand what is wrong because method without HandleServiceCall works just fine...

Help please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of `TResult` will let you know what's wrong. It's `Task<Location[]>`. So you're disposing the proxy (via `Close`) before the asynchronous call is complete.

The fix is to `await` the `Task` before calling `Close`, just like your original code is doing. This should do the trick:

```
public async Task<TResult> HandleServiceCall<TResult>(Func<IPlantOrgQueryService, Task<TResult>> serviceMethod)
{
    ChannelFactory<IQueryService> channel = new ChannelFactory<IQueryService>("SomeServ_IQuery");
    channel.Open();
    IQueryService newProxy = channel.CreateChannel();
    TResult results = await serviceMethod(newProxy);
    ((IChannel)newProxy).Close();

     return results;
}
```

Comment: It exactly what I thought. Thanks!